# Nancy returns the wrong Content Type from an F# controller

Tags: model-view-controller, f#, nancy, razorengine

I've been working up an F# Nancy application using the F# Nancy Application Visual Studio Extension. All has been going well with getting a C# Razor View to render until I tried passing in a model object to the view. The following is my controller:

```
namespace AspNetHost1

open Nancy
open Models

type IndexModule() as self =
    inherit NancyModule()

    do 
        self.Get.["/"]      <- fun _ -> self.Index()
        self.Get.["/Home"]  <- fun _ -> self.Home()

    member self.Index() =
        self.View.["index.cshtml"] :> obj

    member self.Home() =
        let login = new Login()
        login.UserName <- "Francis"
        self.View.["Home.cshtml", login] :> obj
```

The `Login` class is defined as:

```
type Login (userName: string) = 
    let userName = userName
    new() = new Login("")
    member val LoginId = 0 with get, set
    member val UserName = userName with get, set
    member val PasswordHash = "" with get, set
    member val IsActive = true with get, set
```

I'm using VS 2013 Community edition, but i don't think that makes and difference, and its a .NET 4.5 project with F# 3.

The Index View works fine, but the Home view gives a CS1001 compilation error from the Razor compiler. whether I'm referencing the model object or not. As soon as I use the other overload to create the view, everything compiles again. There is some evidence that it it trying to return my model as Json.

Has anybody had similar experiences, or knows what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

After leaving this for a while in frustration I came back to it yesterday with a though about whether it had something to do with F# classes.

So first I tried to make the model a simple string, and it worked! I then decided to add a C# project to the solution and reference it from the Nancy F# Web project and then use that - it worked!

I was even able to use it in my F# repository, retrieve it from the database and pass it back in an F# Option! So I had a look at the decompiled source code from the two DLLs using JetBrain's dotPeek to see if I could see any differences. And, after playing around for a while to see what I could get to change, I concluded that the only difference is the auto-inserted attribute on the F# Class:

```
 [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.ObjectType)]
```

So, I can get the Razor View working if I use C# entities. The one thing that I couldn't get working was Razor finding my model class if I made it a strongly typed view!

My next port of call is to check out the Nancy source code and trace what happens when I submit my request for the view, supplying a model.